# Disabling select option with specific value in Ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I am using Ember 1.4 and I am having an issue getting a select element(attempt_interval) to be disabled when another select element(max_attempt_count) has a value of 1. It works fine when in my testing environment when not using Ember. Any ideas?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=max_attempt_count]', function(){

    var ctrl=$(this);//$(this) refers to current clicked button
    var maxAttempt =ctrl.closest('form').find('select[name=max_attempt_count]');
    var interval =ctrl.closest('form').find('select[name=attempt_interval]');

    $(maxAttempt).change(function() { //each time a user selects a option (event triggered)
        $(interval).prop('disabled', this.value == 1);
    }).change(); //auto execute when page load
} )
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="ember894" class="ember-view ember-select chosen-select" name="max_attempt_count" style="display: none;">
 <option id="ember907" class="ember-view" value="1">
 <option id="ember908" class="ember-view" value="2"><option id="ember909" class="ember-view" value="3">
 <option id="ember910" class="ember-view" value="4">
 <option id="ember911" class="ember-view" value="5">
</select>
```

Comment: Ember 1.4 never existed. Do you mean 2.4 ? I'm not being picky it just makes a huge difference if you are on Ember 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have 2 select menus with values *attempt_interval* and *max_attempt_count* .

And max *max_attempt_count* select needs to be disabled when *attempt_interval* is equal to 1

You should make a computed property like this.

*js file*

```
maxAttemptDisabled: Ember.computed.equal('attempt_interval', 1)
```

*hbs*

```
{{select data=blah selection=attempt_interval}}

{{select data=blah2 selection=max_attempt_count disabled=maxAttemptDisabled}}
```

In case you wanna hide it

```
{{#unless maxAttempltDisabled}}
       {{select data=blah2 selection=max_attempt_count}}
{{/unless}}
```

If youre using ember 2 (a way but not preffered. NB! requires is-equal helper)

```
{{select data=blah2 selection=max_attempt_count disabled=(is-equal attempt_interval 1)}}
```

Comment: To hide DOM element we can use, isVisible property instead of unless block helper. {{select data=blah selection=attempt_interval isVisible=maxAttempltDisabled}}

Comment: mkay, nice discovery (Y)